# Separate CSS link based on window width in NextJS

Tags: css, next.js, css-modules

Is it possible to make NextJS link stylesheets based on media queries? I'm using css modules. Example:

**CSS module file:**

```css
@media(max-width: 800px) {
  .myClass{
    /* ...mobile styles */
  }
}
@media(min-width: 800px) {
  .myClass{
    /* ...desktopstyles */
  }
}
.myClass {
  /* all media styles */
}
```

**How NextJS creates the links:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/<bundle-number>.css">
```

**Desired behavior:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/<bundle-number-desktop>.css" media="(min-width: 800px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/<bundle-number-mobile>.css" media="(max-width: 800px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/<bundle-number-all-medias>.css" data-n-p="">
```

I couldn't find any solution in my researches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is, *well yes, but actually no*. 
If you want the code splitted automatically and handled by Next.js, I don't think it is possible for now (or maybe unless you tweak the custom server approach).

But for your workaround, simply just add the CSS file with the good ol' days? 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" your-property-goes-here>`

I think you can put this through the `_document.{tsx|jsx}`. 
The drawback for your particular case is, you mentioned that you're using CSS module, correct? I'm afraid that you would've probably should stick back to the classic class/className.